# Load an anime.js animation html file as a background to a section in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anime.js

I am trying to use this a anime.js file as a background to a website banner. Here

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="icon fa-diamond"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- Animation Script -->
    <!--
      <script>
        document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="animation/index.html"></object>';
      </script>
    -->
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
    <p>MORE TEXT</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am loading the script like this but the problem is it replaces and loads the `inner` div completely. How should I make it load on the entire section? I also want the inner div intact.

Comment: You need an element to put it in, as well as an element that you *don't* want to put it in.  (You can have 2 sections or 2 divs in 1 section.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're completely overwriting the HTML of the `#banner` element, and completely wiping out its existing contents.

To fix this create the `object` element separately, then use `appendChild()` to add it to the `#banner` element:

```js
var obj = document.createElement('object');
obj.type = 'text/html';
obj.data = 'animation/index.html';
document.getElementById('banner').appendChild(obj);
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="icon fa-diamond"></span>
    </div>
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
    <p>MORE TEXT</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but it only solves half of my problem. Appending this html adds the file below the inner div, I want to load the inner div on top of the html  file. The animation loads below the div not behind it.

Comment: Simply put I want to overlap these divs.

Comment: In that case this is the HTML and JS you need to use, you just need to use CSS to set `#banner` to `position: relative` and both of the contained elements to `position: absolute; top: 0`